# sql show difference in one column based on the sum of another column on another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table like following

| job_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2948 | 0 |
| 2947 | 3 |
| 2949 | 34 |
| 2950 | 4 |

And I have another table like following

| job_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2949 | 10 |
| 2949 | 20 |

If I run `SELECT job_id, sum(quantity) FROM arr_database.test_table group by job_id;`

| job_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2949 | 30 |

As we can see , `job_id` is common in both table , I want to deduct sum of quantity which is available in second table from first table .

So the output will be like following as sum of quantity for job_id 2949 is 30 , and I dedcut that 30 from table one where job id is 2949 .

| job_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2948 | 0 |
| 2947 | 3 |
| 2949 | 4 |
| 2950 | 4 |

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ? is this mysql ?

Comment: `SELECT t1.job_id,  t1.quantity - t2.quantity  as quantity FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT job_id, sum(quantity) as quantity FROM table2 GROUP BY job_id) as t2 ON t1.job_id = t2.job_id;` ought to do the trick. May have to wrap the `t2.quantity` up with a `zerofnull()` type of function depending on RDBMS.

Comment: @SelVazi yes mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the job_id is unique in the first table then you can simply do it using this arithmitic `max()` - `sum()` :

```
select t1.job_id, max(t1.quantity) - sum(case when t2.quantity then t2.quantity else 0 end) as quantity
from table1 as t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.job_id = t2.job_id
group by job_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gwawmU1c)

If it is not unique then do it as follows :

```
select c1.job_id, c1.quantity - coalesce(c2.quantity, 0)
from (
  select job_id, sum(quantity) as quantity
  from table1
  group by job_id
) c1
left join (
   select job_id, sum(quantity) as quantity
   from table2
   group by job_id
) c2 on c1.job_id = c2.job_id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dvB5wtox)

Answer (score 1):

```
with    
    t1 as (select job_id, sum(quantity) as qty from table1),
    t2 as (select job_id, sum(quantity) as qty from table2)
select
    t1.job_id,
    t1.qty - coalesce(t2.qty, 0) as qty
from 
    t1
    left join
    t2 on t2.job_id = t1.job_id
```